# Script works in CodeCademy but not at command line

Tags: python, command-line, python-3.6

I am a novice programmer teaching myself Python using CodeCademy. I wrote a script on my own in order to check the knowledge that I have learned thus far. The intention of this script is to print the names of people that are available on a certain weekend, based on a user-input date and cross-referenced with lists of dates that I wrote in the script.

The strange part is that this script functions exactly as intended in CodeCademy's Python environment, with no errors. It returns exactly the results I expect every single time. However, this is not the case when I try to run the script manually using Python 3.6.1 on my computer via the command line. Rather, it returns the same result every single time no matter what. Here is my code:

```
#script to tell who is free on a certain weekend
input_date = input("Please input the weekend on which you are looking for in         
the format mm.dd (ex. weekend of June 30th is 06.30): ")
ben_dates = [06.16,06.23,06.30,07.07,07.14,08.04,08.11]
david_dates = [06.16,06.23,06.30,07.14,07.28,08.04,08.11]
danyall_dates = [06.30,07.07,07.14,07.21,07.28,08.04,08.11]
kevin_dates= [06.16,06.23,06.30,07.07,07.14,07.21,07.28,08.04,08.11,08.18]
manan_dates=[06.16,07.14,07.21,07.28,08.04]
jack_dates=[06.30,07.07,07.14,07.21,07.28,08.04]

free_people = "The people free on this date are: "
free_people_orig = free_people


for date in ben_dates:
  if input_date == date:
    free_people = free_people + "Ben, "


for date in david_dates:
  if input_date == date:
    free_people = free_people + "David, "

for date in danyall_dates:
  if input_date == date:
    free_people = free_people + "Danyall, "

for date in kevin_dates:
  if input_date == date:
    free_people = free_people + "Kevin, "

for date in manan_dates:
  if input_date == date:
    free_people = free_people + "Manan, "

for date in jack_dates:
  if input_date == date:
    free_people = free_people + "Jack, "

if len(free_people) == len(free_people_orig):
  free_people = "No one is free on this weekend."

print(free_people)
```

So, for example, if the user inputs '06.30' on CodeCademy, the program will print 'The people free on this date are: Ben, David, Danyall, Kevin, Jack,' and this would be the correct result.

However, if run in command line, the same input will print 'No one is free on this weekend' and I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.

I have tried several different variations of while and for loops, using if, elif, and else statements, changing the conditions and format of the free_people string and what triggers it to be modified, as well as many other tactics for going about this specific solution, yet none have been able to make the script run properly. What am I doing wrong here that it works in CodeCademy but not on my computer?

Also, I am aware that this is far from the best way to create a script for this task, and even then my implementation could certainly be better. However, I am a beginner, and am writing this script with the primary concern of testing specific skills that I have learned by writing a script that could have some modicum of basic use for myself. I am only interested in figuring out why this specific version of this specific script does not work.

P.S. This is my first post on StackOverflow, my apologies if I formatted this post incorrectly.

Comment: Input_date is a `str` and you’re trying to compare it with `float`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are inputting a string, when it needs to be a float. Every element in your lists are floats, and you are trying to see if an element of type string exists in any of those lists, which is `False`.

Try this:

```
input_date = float(input("Please input the weekend on which you are looking for in the "
                         "format mm.dd (ex. weekend of June 30th is 06.30): "))
```

Comment: This entirely fixed the problem, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider marking this response as answered so other users know your question has an answer. Thank you.

Comment: I know, I will accept this answer as soon as I am able. StackOverflow blocks me from selecting an answer for 10 minutes, and that time period is not yet up. Thank you